# What is the difference between the `\Hat` and `\hat` macros, the `\Dot` and `\dot` macros, and similar?

Tags: amsmath, accents

I remember reading about capitalized forms of some accent macros, such as `\Hat`, `\Dot`, and so on, and *possibly* their use was related to specific typographic corrections. I think it was in an AMSLaTeX-related document, but now I don't manage to find out where. (They don't seem to appear in [amsldoc.pdf](http://tug.ctan.org/info/amslatex/english/amsldoc.pdf), and I thought I had seen them there).

I can indeed use them in a LaTeX document with the `amsmath` package (without specifying any `\newcommand`): no undefined-macro errors appear. But I can't really see any typographic difference from the lowercase `\hat`, `\dot`, etc in the pdf output.

What is the difference between these capitalized forms and the usual lowercase ones? and in which packages do they appear?

Comment: `amsmath` has `\def\Hat{\hat}` (and similar) so they are exactly the same. I have vague memories of the difference being a remnant of earlier version which has been kept for compatibility but I cannot confirm that.

Comment: @campa Thank you. So probably I had also seen them in an earlier version. What you say answers my question: there's no difference between them. Please feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: @campa It seems indeed they appeared in [version 1.2, 1995](https://folk.ntnu.no/oyvinso/ICRA/Proceedings/Instructions/amsldoc.ps), to obtain better positioning for stacked accents.

Comment: My recollection is that in the old days ordinary "accents" could not be stacked, e.g. `\dot{\hat{x}}` would not work (or maybe just not look good, I do not remember) but with the uppercase versions it did, i.e. one had to use `\Dot{\Hat{x}}` or `\Dot{\hat{x}}`. This is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [implementation notes](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf):

> The commands `\Hat`, `\Tilde`, ..., are supported as synonyms of `\hat`, `\tilde`, ..., for backward compatibility.

The origins of this go back to the original AmS-TeX macro package which defined the capitalized versions with some additional ceremony beyond what the lowercase versions did but said ceremony is not necessary in LaTeX.

Comment: I believe that `amsmath` version 1 still had the distinction; the capitalized macros were necessary when stacking accents (like in AMS-TeX), but version 2 changed the code so the capitalized macros became superfluous.